# Parsing XML in R with SYSTEM DTD declaration

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to parse [DBLP](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/) dataset in R. The XML has DOCTYPE with the following `<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">` definition. The underlying DTD is external and is found [here](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/).

When I try to parse the locally downloaded XML in R with the code given below, I get errors stating a few entities defined in DTD are not defined.

```
require("XML")
url = "file:///Downloads/dblp.xml"
xmlFile = xmlTreeParse(url)
```

Error Message (sample):

```
Entity 'ouml' not defined
Detected an entity reference loop
Entity 'eacute' not defined
Detected an entity reference loop
Entity 'eacute' not defined
```

These are due to the fact that the entities are not valid XML character and are encoding for accented characters. However, they have been defined in the DTD in their numeric format.

Is there an example how to go about parsing this XML file by applying the DTD?

Comment: I know `xml2::read_xml` exposes libxml2's `DTDLOAD` option which might be helpful, though I haven't played with it much. There may be a way with the `encoding` parameter of `xmlTreeParse`, too.

Comment: `xmlTreeParse(url, options=XML::DTDLOAD)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr: please post your comment as an answer.