# DTD parsing error in R

Tags: r, xml, dtd

I've got a bit of a problem with an xml tree in r. I have a treebank, containing the corpus - stuff I really need. What I want is to take the XML files, parse them with the help of the DTD on my computer, and then just create a corpus afterwards.

So far I've tried

```
xmlTreeParse(doc, options=XML::DTDLOAD)
```

and

```
xmlParse(doc)
```

and also

```
parseDTD(dtd)
```

but all of them throw back an error. First two still say "entity not defined", and the parsing function gives back "failed to load external entity "yaddayadda.dtd"". In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312489/parsing-xml-in-r-with-system-dtd-declaration) question the treeparse function was given as an answer, but it does not work for me. The xml files have a SYSTEM "../yaddayadda.dtd" designation.

What I plan to do with this, is to somehow create a VCorpus object in the tm package from the parsed text, to use it in later textmining research.

Could you help me please? Will provide further details if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parser, which you are telling to load the DTD, is seeing a reference to "../yaddayadda.dtd" and not finding it.

The most likely cause is that you have no file named "yaddayadda.dtd" on the appropriate file system, or that you have it in the wrong place; the parser should be looking for it in the directory one level up from the XML document which refers to it.

If you have it in what you think is the right location, then apparently you and the parser do not agree on what the right location is.  Good luck.